# the beta-distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, beta-function

The four pictures below are $\beta(1,1),\beta(2,1),\beta(3,1)$ and $\beta(3,2).$
Are they **normalized** to be p.d.f.'s? If not, can a normalization be given ?

[image]

Comment: They certainly **look** normalized, but of course we can't tell exactly from an image. How did you produce them?

Comment: @joriki Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057948/binomial-distribution-conjugate-posterior)

Comment: What should I see there? I see the same images and no formula or code that shows how they were produced. By definition, if they're beta distributions, they're normalized. Perhaps I don't understand what you're asking.